# React Native: Error while updating property 'transform' of a view managed by: RCTView in Android

Tags: react-native, animation, android-emulator

I am developing some application with React Native. First, I was checking Android and IOS at the same time. After that, I made a mistake. I continued with only IOS. After a while, I had run in Android Emulator then I saw the app is crashed (Error is attached). I doubt the animations. I will not add all the codes of the project to not waste anyone's time. I have added the codes of animated CardFlip. It gives the error when only I opened the page which has the animated component. I hope that somebody might help me with this.

[image]

**CardFlip Component**

```
import React, { ReactNode, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, StyleSheet, ViewStyle, View, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { isAndroid } from 'Utils/Device';
import { Helpers } from 'Theme/index';

interface CardFlipProps {
    condition?: boolean
    children: [ReactNode, ReactNode]
    containerStyle?: ViewStyle|Array<ViewStyle>
}

const CardFlip: React.FunctionComponent<CardFlipProps> = ({ children, condition = true, containerStyle = {} }): JSX.Element => {
    const [flip, setFlip] = useState(false);
    const [rotate] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

    const startAnimation = ({ toRotate }) => {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.spring(rotate, {
                toValue: toRotate,
                friction: 8,
                tension: 1,
            }),
        ]).start();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (flip) {
            startAnimation({ toRotate: 1 });
        } else {
            startAnimation({ toRotate: 0 });
        }
    }, [flip]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!condition) {
            setFlip(false);
        }
    }, [condition]);

    const interpolatedFrontRotate = rotate.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
    });

    const interpolatedBackRotate = rotate.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: ['180deg', '0deg'],
    });

    const frontOpacity = rotate.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [1, 0.7],
    });

    const backOpacity = rotate.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1],
        outputRange: [0.7, 1],
    });

    const perspective = isAndroid() ? undefined : 1000;

    return (
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ () => condition && setFlip(!flip) }>
            <View style={ containerStyle }>
                <Animated.View style={ [
                    style.card,
                    { transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedFrontRotate }, { perspective }] },
                    { opacity: frontOpacity },
                ] }>
                    { children[0] }
                </Animated.View>
                <Animated.View style={ [
                    style.card,
                    { transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedBackRotate }, { perspective }] },
                    { opacity: backOpacity },
                ] }>
                    { children[1] }
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
};

interface Styles {
    card: ViewStyle
}

const style = StyleSheet.create<Styles>({
    card: {
        ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',
        ...Helpers.center,
    },
});

export default CardFlip;
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the perspective property in the transform?

Comment: @sfratini Actually I had supposed to have tried that :). Thank you so much it worked. You should add the answer. Thus, I can approve it as the correct answer. While I was doing the flip animation, I had reviewed the below code. And, I had taken the perspective from the below code. Anyway, Thanks. I hope that the answer helps people who faced the same issue.

https://github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native/blob/master/bonuses/flip-card/components/Card.tsx

Comment: Thanks! I just posted it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just moving my comment as answer as requested. It seems that the perspective value could be null or a bug in Android so either removing it or using it conditionally should work.

Comment: I agree with that. At least, It should throw an error which is pointing the perspective. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

in the lines
`{ transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedFrontRotate }, { perspective }] },` and 
`{ transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedBackRotate }, { perspective }] },` : removing perspective or implementing it as `{ transform: [{ rotateY: interpolatedFrontRotate }, { perspective: perspective }] },` may solve your problem. In addition, you can rename the `const perspective` to avoid confusion.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had tried your solution. Unfortunately, It didn't work as we expected. I approved the correct answer that you can see above.